React state not being set after specific action
I'm currently struggling updating the state of a complex interface with an action from a child component. Here are the main points:

I have a child component autocomplete.component.tsx that is basically a field with items suggested below
I have a form.tsx component where I'm calling autocomplete.component.tsx and I'm displaying the field with some fake data and with a dropdown
I can see the state being updated when I'm typing in the field correctly and the complex object (interface) showing it updated properly.
When I'm clicking on the suggested item in the autocomplete.component.tsx you can see in the console from the codesandbox devbox showing the correct selected value, but the state was not updated to the complex object. I know state is async but is not updating when submitting the form (you can see handleSubmit() method) and Save button is not updated.

I'm using ReactJS + Vite + Typescript
import IMovimiento from "../IMovimiento";
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { movimientoDefaultState } from "../movimientoDefaultState";
import { SingleValue } from "react-select";
import Select from "react-select";

import IOption from "../IOption";
import AutocompleteCustom from "./autocomplete.component";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import ILugar from "../ILugar";

const GastoForm = () => {
  let ioptionLugar = { value: "", label: "" } as SingleValue<IOption>;
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [lugares, setLugares] = useState(Array<ILugar>);

  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState<string[]>();
  //Stuff to declare
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState<IMovimiento>(
    movimientoDefaultState
  );
  const [, setLugar] = useState<SingleValue<IOption> | null>(null);

  //Methods
  const handleFieldChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, [name]: value });
  };

  //When dropdown changes
  const handleDropDownChange = (
    selectedOption: SingleValue<IOption>,
    name: string
  ): void => {
    const { value, label } = { ...selectedOption };
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, [name]: value });
    const ioption = { value: value, label: label };
    console.log(formFields);

    if (name === "LugarId") {
      setLugar(selectedOption);
      ioptionLugar = ioption;
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formFields);
    return;
  };

  /*AUTOCOMPLETE*/
  const changeHandlerAutocomplete = async (
    e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    //You can see here the state is being updated properly everytime I type...
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, [name]: value });

    if (value !== "" && value.length <= 2) return;

    //Now we search for a possible match
    if (value === "") {
      setIsOpen(false);
      setSuggestions([]);
      return;
    }

    //Faking results from a source...
    const response = ["Test", "Test2", "Test3"];
    if (response) {
      setSuggestions(response);
      setIsOpen(true);
      return;
    }

    setIsOpen(false);
    setSuggestions([]);
  };

  //Method to try and grab the option from the list of autocomplete
  const selectedItem = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const descripcion = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-item");

    //Fake variable that I'm using to simulate another functionality, for the sake of the example is like this
    const fakeLugar = 2;
    //const ids = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-ids");
    const selectedOptionInAutocomplete =
      descripcion !== null ? descripcion.split("-")[0].trim() : "";
    console.log(selectedOptionInAutocomplete);
    /*I EXPECT HERE FOR DESCRIPCION TO BE ONE OF THE AUTOCOMPLETE OPTIONS, 
    NOT THE TEXT I'M WRITING.
    ALSO I EXPECT FOR THE TEXTFIELD TO HAVE THE AUTOCOMPLETE TEXT SINCE I'M 
    TELLING THE STATE TO BE MY OPTION CHOSEN
    */
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, Descripcion: selectedOptionInAutocomplete });
    setFormFields({
      ...formFields,
      ["Descripcion"]: selectedOptionInAutocomplete,
    });

    //Handle the dropdown changes to update state, faking place 2 always to see state
    const selectedLugar = lugares.find((i) => i.LugarId === fakeLugar);
    ioptionLugar = {
      value: selectedLugar?.LugarId.toString(),
      label: selectedLugar?.Descripcion,
    };
    handleDropDownChange(ioptionLugar, "LugarId");
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  /*AUTOCOMPLETE*/

  const mapperLugar = (): IOption[] => {
    return lugares.map((item) => {
      return { value: item.LugarId, label: item.Descripcion };
    }) as unknown as IOption[];
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDropDowns = async () => {
      const responseLugar = [
        { LugarId: 1, Descripcion: "Place 1" },
        { LugarId: 2, Descripcion: "Place 2" },
      ] as ILugar[];

      setLugares(responseLugar);
    };

    getDropDowns();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Col md={6}>
            <AutocompleteCustom
              name="Descripcion"
              value={formFields.Descripcion}
              isOpen={isOpen}
              items={suggestions}
              changeHandler={changeHandlerAutocomplete}
              selectedItemHandler={(
                e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>
              ) => selectedItem(e)}
            >
              {formFields.Descripcion}
            </AutocompleteCustom>
          </Col>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Select
              options={mapperLugar()}
              onChange={(selectedOption: SingleValue<IOption>) =>
                handleDropDownChange(selectedOption, "LugarId")
              }
              value={ioptionLugar}
              theme={(theme) => ({
                ...theme,
                colors: {
                  ...theme.colors,
                  primary: "#01A3FF",
                  primary25: "#01A3FF",
                  neutral0: "#1e1e25",
                },
                borderRadius: 4,
              })}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Save
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default GastoForm;

autocomplete.component.tsx
import { ChangeEvent, PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

interface AutocompleteCustomProps {
  children: string;
  name: string;
  changeHandler?: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  clickHandler?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  value: string | number | undefined;
  items: string[] | undefined;
  isOpen: boolean;
  selectedItemHandler: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
}

const AutocompleteCustom = ({
  children,
  name,
  value,
  changeHandler,
  clickHandler,
  items,
  isOpen,
  selectedItemHandler,
}: PropsWithChildren<AutocompleteCustomProps>) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{children}</p>
      <div className="easy-autocomplete">
        <Form.Control
          name={name}
          placeholder={children}
          type="text"
          onChange={changeHandler}
          value={value}
          onClick={clickHandler}
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        {items && isOpen && (
          <div className="easy-autocomplete-container">
            <ul
              className=""
              style={isOpen ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}
            >
              {items.map((item, i) => {
                const descripcionValues = item.split(";");
                if (descripcionValues.length === 0) {
                  return (
                    <li key={i}>
                      <div
                        className="eac-item"
                        data-item={item}
                        onClick={(e) => selectedItemHandler(e)}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  );
                }

                //It's a complex item, make it different
                const description = descripcionValues[0];
                const values = descripcionValues[1];
                return (
                  <li key={i}>
                    <div
                      className="eac-item"
                      data-item={description}
                      data-ids={values}
                      onClick={(e) => selectedItemHandler(e)}
                    >
                      {description}
                    </div>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AutocompleteCustom;

App.tsx
import "./App.css";

import GastoForm from "./components/form";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GastoForm />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


IMovimiento.ts - Descripcion is the field I want updated after option is selected
export default interface IMovimiento {
  MovimientoId: number;
  Descripcion: string;
  Monto: number;
  Moneda: string;
  Fecha: Date;
  Ticket: string;
  Estatus: string;
  Transferencia: string | null;
  Observacion: string | undefined;
  CuentaId: number;
  Cuenta: string;
  TipoMovimientoId: number;
  TipoMovimiento: string;
  CategoriaId: number;
  Categoria: string;
  SubCategoriaId: number;
  SubCategoria: string;
  CompradorId: number;
  Comprador: string;
  LugarId: number;
  NombreLugar: string;
  Etiquetas: (string | number | null | undefined)[];
  Mes: string;
  MesSuscripcion: string;
  AnioSuscripcion: string;
  ServicioId: number;
  CuentaIdCredito: number;
  FechaPago: Date | null;
}



The problem in your code is the following (see comments)
//Method to try and grab the option from the list of autocomplete
const selectedItem = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const descripcion = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-item");
  const fakeLugar = 2;
  const selectedOptionInAutocomplete =
    descripcion !== null ? descripcion.split("-")[0].trim() : "";
  console.log(selectedOptionInAutocomplete);
  /*I EXPECT HERE FOR DESCRIPCION TO BE ONE OF THE AUTOCOMPLETE OPTIONS, 
    NOT THE TEXT I'M WRITING.
    ALSO I EXPECT FOR THE TEXTFIELD TO HAVE THE AUTOCOMPLETE TEXT SINCE I'M 
    TELLING THE STATE TO BE MY OPTION CHOSEN
    */
  setFormFields({ ...formFields, Descripcion: selectedOptionInAutocomplete });
  

  // This is not necessary remove it
  /*
  setFormFields({
    ...formFields,
    ["Descripcion"]: selectedOptionInAutocomplete,
  });
  */
  const selectedLugar = lugares.find((i) => i.LugarId === fakeLugar);
  ioptionLugar = {
    value: selectedLugar?.LugarId.toString(),
    label: selectedLugar?.Descripcion,
  };
  
  // HERE is the problem you are setting the formFields here also
  handleDropDownChange(ioptionLugar, "LugarId");
  setIsOpen(false);
};

// lets see the handler

//When dropdown changes
const handleDropDownChange = (
  selectedOption: SingleValue<IOption>,
  name: string
): void => {
  const { value, label } = { ...selectedOption };
  

  // here you are updating again the formFields but at this point in time
  // react is using your previous state to update it (with the old description that is passed in ...formFields)
  // in order to react be aware of the previous state update you need to change it with a callback
  // that is going to receive the current state you updated in selectedItem
  // old code
  //setFormFields({ ...formFields, [name]: value });
  // new code
  setFormFields((prevFormFields) => ({ ...prevFormFields, [name]: value }));
  const ioption = { value: value, label: label };

  if (name === "LugarId") {
    setLugar(selectedOption);
    ioptionLugar = ioption;
  }
};


And another piece of advice, try not to mix spanish with english in your code, pick or english or spanish and stick with it

Yeah that was it, I did not know I had to use a callback to update the previous formFields instead of just calling the usual {...formFields, [name] : value} Thanks and I appreciate the help.
